# Magento 2 - Not registered handle cms_block_listing_data_source

Tags: magento2

I am getting the error "Not registered handle **`cms_block_listing_data_source`**" on the Blocks section of the admin and the error "Not registered handle **`cms_page_listing_data_source`**" on the Pages section of the admin. Everything else in the admin seems to be working okay.

I have come across some answers online but nothing seems to have fixed it so far. These answers say that it is installing a module that has caused the error but I haven't installed a new module for a while which has confused me slightly.

I also have the error "**`Unknown entity type: Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface requested`**" on the front end of my website, I assume this is related to the back-end error but my knowledge isn't the best so not sure how to fix this.

I am using Magento version 2.3.2.

Any help on these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below steps to resolve the issue.

1. remove all data from generated.
2. run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"
3. run "php bin/magento  c:c"
4. run "php bin/magento c:f"
5. run "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"

Comment: Hey Arun, thanks for your reply. After I run the php bin/magento setup:upgrade command it comes back with the error "Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"." How do I fix this please?

Comment: Please don't include command string , check my update answer

Comment: Thank you but that didn't fix it :(